# What is a perfect race?

Tags: chocobo-gp

After one of my races in Chocobo GP, a banner appeared saying I'd had a perfect race. This happened even though I only came in third place.

What does it mean to have a perfect race in Chocobo GP?

[image: Finish! Perfect race!!!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this source](https://ftw.usatoday.com/2022/03/chocobo-gp-review):

> Winning without taking damage will result in a Perfect Race.